# Android with SDL2

Tags: android, sdl2, ndk

How to link native code (it has SDL_CreateWindow) with Java application code? In my case, there `libSDL2.so`, also my `.so` library that uses the SDL. My `method` contains functions `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_Init`

Under Win32 (collected in the dll) it works. Called the "method" and creates a new window. But in the same way by running method, the function works and completes execution without exceptions thrown, but nothing visually appears

*my.cpp*

```
int method(){


    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("test!!!!!!!!!!!", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    return 0;
}

#ifdef ANDROID
    extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ni55an_ndktest_HelloClass_method(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj){  
         return (jint)method();
    }
#endif
```

my.java

```
  static {
        System.loadLibrary("SDL2");
        System.loadLibrary("proj");
    }
    public native int method();
```

Sorry, but I'm forgot do validation for SDL_Init. Initialization fails, and I get an error `Application didn't initialize properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using [the example](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/tree/master/android-project).

In Java application must be [SDLActivity](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java). It calls nativeInit of [SDL_android_main.c](https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c), which must be compiled along with my .so library(like [here](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/blob/master/android-project/jni/src/Android.mk))

`nativeInit` runs the method `SDL_main`, which essentially is the entry point of my library and contains `SDL_Init` and other initialization methods